# How can show a list of authors which have only posted in a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show a list of authors who have posts in a custom post type. What i've done so far is to use the wp_list_authors which only shows the admin posts and doesn't take into account custom posts. What i really want to do is on my Latest news page which has posts from the custom post, 'News' to just show the authors who have posts in that Custom post type.

If anyone could any light to how i can do this then i would be very appreciative :)

Thanks

```
    <?php
$blogusers = wp_list_authors();
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo "<li><a href='#' data-option-value='.".strtolower($user->user_login)."'><div class='flag'>".get_avatar($user->ID, 'description', true).'</div>' . $user->user_login ."</a></li>\n";    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with this function, but you can do it with direct query, something like

```
global $wpdb;
$authors=$wpdb->get_results('select `'.$wpdb->prefix.'users`.`ID`, `'.$wpdb->prefix.'users`.`user_login`, `'.$wpdb->prefix.'users`.`display_name` from `'.$wpdb->prefix.'users` inner join `'.$wpdb->prefix.'posts` on `'.$wpdb->prefix.'users`.`ID`=`'.$wpdb->prefix.'posts`.`post_author` where `post_type`=\'news\' group by `'.$wpdb->prefix.'users`.`ID`;');
//you should do a check if $authors is not null and actually got any records returned.
foreach ( $authors as $user ) 
{
    echo "<li><a href='#' data-option-value='".strtolower($user->user_login)."'><div class='flag'>".get_avatar($user->ID, 'description', true).'</div>' . $user->display_name."</a></li>\n";    
}
```

Comment: Hey Flyer,

Thanks for the speedy answer! I've put that code in but it's now displaying nothing :/ Do you think it could be because i have an author image plugin which is causing a clash?

Comment: @Shaun oh yeah, my bad, try now

Comment: Checked to see if it matches and both are saying 'news' :/ I also tried it with two other of my custom posts and still no results.

Comment: @Shaun yeah, I messed up a bit, updated answer. Should work good now.

Comment: You my sir are a legend! Thanks so much - you've made my day :D

Comment: You're welcome ;) Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem. Cheers.

Comment: You got it. Have a nice day ;)